# Как перенести каждый элемент массива на новою строчку?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
function Team(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.letters = [];
}
Team.prototype.addLetter = function (letter) {
     this.letters.push.apply(this.letters.push, arguments).join('\n');
};
Team.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Name of team - " + this.name +  '\n' +"ltters : " + this.letters;
};
var a = 's';
b='g';
v='d';
var team1 =  new Team('letters');
team1.addLetter(a,b,v);
console.log(team1.toString());
```

Comment: Не работает....

Comment: Лучше уточните вопрос,потому что console.log и так выводит с новой строки

Comment: const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(let it of arr) {
 console.log(it);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще это плохая идея добовлять `\n` к элементам массива. Лучше уж делать это при выводе.

```js
    function Team(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.letters = [];
    }
    Team.prototype.addLetter = function (...letters) {
    for (var i=0; i<letters.length; i++)
         this.letters.push(letters[i]);
    };
    Team.prototype.toString = function () {
      var res = "Name of team - " + this.name +  '\n' +"ltters :\n";
       
      for (var i=0; i<this.letters.length; i++)
        res += this.letters[i]+"\n";
      return  res;
    };
        
   
    var a = 's';
    b='g';
    v='d';
    var team1 =  new Team('letters');
    team1.addLetter(a,b,v);
    console.log(team1.toString());
```